# What is the best c# method you've seen for encapsulating an ADO.Net query

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

We're building a simple ADO.Net infrastructure, and looking for the best practice for creating one or more objects/methods to handle queries to SQL Server.

Such a method could for example, take a connection string and a query (or stored proc), and return a datatable, dataset, etc., with the query results.

How has this worked best for you in the past?  If you could mention what your method signature(s) looked like or include some code, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at NHibernate, LINQ to SQL, ADO.NET Entity Framework or another ORM. They are mostly mature technologies to interact with ADO. Happy coding

Comment: Yes @John is correct. LINQ to SQL only works with SQL Server (2000, 2005 or 2008).

Comment: We hand-coded it for now, but I guess the world is pretty much going to ORMS...will try out some of these when we get a chance.